# Problems with ngx-mask Angular 14.2.10

Tags: angular, typescript, ngx-mask

I'm having trouble using ngx-mask. My version is Angular 14.2.10.

I put this in app.module.ts:

```
import { NgxMaskModule }  from  'ngx-mask';
```

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
  NgxMaskModule.forRoot()]
```

[image: My error image]

Answer (score 4):

Your ngx-mask version is waiting for angular v15, not v14.
Try this

```
npm i ngx-mask@14.2.4
```